# Does sql-alchemy filter accept multiple parameters?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I am following a flask/sqlalchemy tutorial and I am familiar with `query.filter` however, I don't understand what this code mean:
`Question.query.filter(Question.id.notin_(previous_questions), Question.category == category_id).all()`
Can someone explain to me how the `filter` got 2 parameters and what does `notin_` mean?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is equivalent to using two `filter`s:

```py
Question.query.filter(
    Question.id.notin_(previous_questions)
).filter(
    Question.category == category_id
).all()
```

`notin_` literally means *this is not inside this other thing*.
In particular in your case `previous_questions` should be a list of `id`s and so you are filtering out every `Question` whose `id` is inside `previous_questions`.